# Inverting a VAR - looking for a good resource

Tags: time-series, econometrics, vector-autoregression

I am having trouble with something that should be pretty basic.

I need to invert a VAR (vector autoregression). Everything I have read just brushes past the actual inversion process, taking for granted that I already know how to invert a VAR. Does anyone know a good source (book, journal article, website) that walks through inverting? I've looked at Diebold's Elements of Forecasting and Enders' Applied Economic Times Series, as well as other sources with good coverage of VARs, but I can't find a good explanation of the basics of working with VARs.

I'm working with a VAR(4) two variable model (nothing exogenous), but I think I can just rewrite that as a VAR(1) and then invert. Though I could certainly be wrong about that.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but shouldn't you be able to write the series as a matrix? i.e. Column names would be y, yt-1, yt-2, yt-3, yt-4, xt-1, xt-2, xt-3, xt-4. You should then be able to invert it same as any other matrix I would think

Comment: I think "inversion" in terms of a VAR means something different than it does in matrix algebra. I think it means putting a VAR in vector moving average form/representation. Could I be wrong about that though?

Comment: are you trying to estimate the MA component of a VARMA by any chance?

Comment: Sadly, no. At least I don't think that's what this involves. I am trying to use the Quah & Vahey (1995) method for calculating core inflation, which requires putting a VAR into VMA format.

Comment: Gotcha. Not having read the paper and lacking the time do so at the moment, I can only guess at what that might involve, though from everything you've said (and correct me if I'm wrong), it attempts to evaluate time-series inflation by modeling the error term from a VAR model. Is that correct? Also, I've only had time briefly glance at it, but maybe http://www.econ.ohio-state.edu/dejong/note6.pdf section 1.1.2 might be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Cross-posted and answered [here](http://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/5490/var-inversion-looking-for-a-good-resource).